# error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 401 Unauthorized"}

Tags: node.js

please help me in this problem that i got polling_error

i gonna to create a bot in telegram and customize that for my own

but when i run the program i got some error like this :

> node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises is deprecated.

and another error like this :

> error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 401 Unauthorized"}

how can i fix this problem?

the complete code is here :

```js
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = '***';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    let Hi = "hi";
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(Hi) === 0) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,"Hello dear user");
    }
});
```

Comment: `401` means `Unauthorized`. Is it token valid? Can try using a freshly generated token?

Comment: yes.
exactly.
solve that problem
thank you
but ''polling_error'' exist yet

Comment: revoke the bot's api token - https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/488#issuecomment-399010905

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const Agent = require('socks5-https-client/lib/Agent')

const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN, {
    polling: true,
    request: {
        agentClass: Agent,
        agentOptions: {
            socksHost: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_HOST,
            socksPort: parseInt(process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_PORT),
            // If authorization is needed:
            // socksUsername: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_USERNAME,
            // socksPassword: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_PASSWORD
        }
    }
})
```